# How can I run "npm test" from webstorm file watcher

Tags: unit-testing, npm, webstorm

Is there a way to run `npm test` from a watcher in webstorm. I know I can create a run configuration from NPM but then I have to trigger it manually, but I want to run my tests on every file change.

Answer (score 6):

```
Program: path/to/node
Arguments: path/to/npm-cli.js run-script test
Working directory: <folder where your package.json is located, $ProjectFileDir$, for example>
```

Not sure why you need it though... I'd suggest using existing test runners instead (karma, mocha, node-unit) - WebStorm provides good integration with them, and some of them support 'auto-testing' (rerunning on spec file change)

Comment: How do you automatically run npm test when a file is saved?

Comment: you can set it up as a file watcher using instructions above, or use Gulp/Grunt/etc watch tasks...